# Filter Django Admin queryset where related OnetoOne already exists

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm looking to implement a filter on my queryset within django-admin to avoid the error message "already exists"

The table is a master mapping table where IDs are mapped from different sources.

IDs can only be mapped once thus most fields are OneToOne.

I've set up my mapping model like so

```
class Dim_Fund_Manager_Mapping(Trackable):
    fund_manager_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
    sharepoint_fund_manager = models.OneToOneField(sharepoint_fund_manager, models.DO_NOTHING)  
    evestment_fund_manager = models.OneToOneField(evestment_fund_manager, models.DO_NOTHING)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('sharepoint_fund_manager', 'evestment_fund_manager'),)
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fund Manager Mapping Master'
```

When a map is made in admin I would like those sharepoint_fund_manager and evestment_fund_manager to no longer appear in the queryset.

```
@admin.register(Dim_Fund_Manager_Mapping)
class ChampFundManagerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return qs = super().get_queryset(request).select_related(
            'sharepoint_fund_manager', 
            'evestment_fund_manager',
        )
```

This is as far as I've gotten to with my knowledge.

Does anybody have some code/help please

I probably don't wont to filter out the queryset when displaying it's only when using the form within the admin

```
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ChampFundManagerAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['sharepoint_fund_manager'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{} {}".format(obj.final_publications_fund_manager_id, obj.manager_name)
        form.base_fields['evestment_fund_manager'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: "{} {}".format(obj.evestment_fund_manager_id_bk, obj.manager_name)
        return form
```

**UPDATE**

I made a little change to my get_form method adding

```
form.base_fields['sharepoint_fund_manager'].queryset = sharepoint_fund_manager.objects.filter(sharepoint_fund_manager_id__isnull=True)
```

and now nothing is returned so i'm getting closer, changing to true has no effect

Answer (score 0):

sorted it out

Whilst filtering the right object i was not filtering the right key

```
form.base_fields['sharepoint_fund_manager'].queryset = sharepoint_fund_manager.objects.filter(dim_fund_manager_mapping__isnull=True)
```